# Search array and find all the values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays . One with array of objects and other plain array.

Need to search the first array from all the levels of first array.

```
let arr1 = [{"LEVEL":1},{"LEVEL":2},{"LEVEL":3,"POSITION":"FCONTROLLER"}, 
            {"LEVEL":4,"POSITION":"RGM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GMH"},{"LEVEL":6},{"LEVEL":7,"POSITION":"EGM"}]

let arr2 = [1,3,5]
```

**Output :**

```
 ["FCONTROLLER","GM","GMH"]
```

I tried to use reduce method but gives empty result.

```
  arr2.reduce((a, o) => (o.merged==='1'||o.merged==='3'||o.merged==='5' && a.push(o.value), a), [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexOf to search for the index of the element level you want in arr2, in case you find, you should return the object, for example :

```
 let arr1 = [{"LEVEL":1},{"LEVEL":2},{"LEVEL":3,"POSITION":"FCONTROLLER"}, 
            {"LEVEL":4,"POSITION":"RGM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GMH"},{"LEVEL":6},{"LEVEL":7,"POSITION":"EGM"}]

 let arr2 = [1,3,5]

const output =arr1.filter((item) => {
  return arr2.indexOf(item.LEVEL) !== -1
});
```

It will return every object that object.LEVEL is in arr2.

Comment: But I do not want LEVEL 1 as it doesnt have position

Comment: You can use :

return (arr2.indeOf(item.LEVEL) !== -1) && (item.POSITION)

Answer (score 1):

While reducing `arr1`, check if the current object has a `POSITION` value, and if its `LEVEL` is included in `arr2`. If both are `true` push it to the accumulator:

```js
const arr1 = [{"LEVEL":1},{"LEVEL":2},{"LEVEL":3,"POSITION":"FCONTROLLER"}, 
            {"LEVEL":4,"POSITION":"RGM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GMH"},{"LEVEL":6},{"LEVEL":7,"POSITION":"EGM"}]

const arr2 = [1,3,5]

const result = arr1.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(o.POSITION && arr2.includes(o.LEVEL)) {
    r.push(o.POSITION)
  }
  
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```